# Matrix3D for a positive rotation around z in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix

Let P be a Point3D such that P = {1,0,0} . I need to define a rotation around the Z axis of +45deg and apply it to P. Under a right-hand convention, the transformation M is defined:

M =

```
0.707 -0.707 0 0    
0.707 0.707 0 0     
0 0 1 0             
0 0 0 1
```

Mathematically:

M x P =

```
0.707 -0.707 0 0         1           0.707
0.707 0.707 0 0     X    0       =   0.707
0 0 1 0                  0           0
0 0 0 1                  1           1
```

here is my C# code:

```
    private void testMatrix3D() {
        double angle_rad = Math.PI/4;
        double cos = Math.Cos(angle_rad);
        double sin = Math.Sin(angle_rad);
        Matrix3D mat = new Matrix3D(cos, -sin, 0, 0, sin, cos, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

        Point3D p = new Point3D(1, 0, 0);

        Point3D transformedP = mat.Transform(p);


        Debug.WriteLine("p = " + p);
        Debug.WriteLine("mat = " + mat);
        Debug.WriteLine("transformedP = " + transformedP);

    }
```

Unfortunately, the result is transformedP = {0.707, -0.707, 0} and NOT transformedP= {0.707, 0.707, 0}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WPF stores vectors in matrices row-wise you need to exchange those:

```
Matrix3D mat = new Matrix3D(cos, sin, 0, 0, -sin, cos, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks @JeffRson . What does the Transform() method does in terms of matrix multiplication then? I assume this is not  p = mat X p .

Comment: if i understand correctly the answer, Transform() does exactly what you expect it to do, you just filled your matrix the wrong way by mistaking yourself between rows and columns. 
btw, whats WPF ?

Comment: I think it's not only a multiplication in the general case because the 4th row contains offsets (addition), but in your case this doesn't matter -- @Guiroux: WPF is "Windows Presentation Foundation", see there.